# Why should you keep your API Secret and key hidden?

Tags: android, api, security, twitter

I was thinking about adding a twitter feed function of read only to one of my Android apps, so it lets people know when I made a new app. All the guides on how to add this hides the API key and secret.

Can someone tell me why?

I understand if it had a read and write function. But, giving it only shows a read function. I don't understand why they are hidden

Comment: you want to tweet from your android app right?

Comment: No I use twitter to tell people when a new app comes out, that or when a new video on my YouTube channel comes out. I am trying to make it where the app will just read and look for an update from my company profile. when a change happens, the app will notify the person.

I'm thinking about making a video and adding to my git the app I will be adding it to.  But all the guides hide the API Key and Secret on a read online. I was just wondering why, and if there is something I'm overlooking in security

Comment: those 2 elements identify you whenever you make a request to the API. you don't want someone to impersonate you.

Comment: Thanks. If you want, you can "answer the question" so I can give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 2 elements identify you whenever you make a request to the API.

You don't want someone to impersonate you, because you agreed to T&Cs that define how you are supposed to use the API.

Typically that includes how much you can use the API (particularly relevant when you have a paid plan), what you are allowed to do with it and what you are not allowed to do with it.

Not keeping those elements secret may expose you to fraudulent use, and you may be liable for it.

You might want to ask in further detail on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) the implications of that.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone wanting to hide their stuff on Github. I found an article on it https://24ways.org/2013/keeping-parts-of-your-codebase-private-on-github/